# Texworks syntax highlighting not working on windows 8 and 8.1

Tags: miktex, windows, highlighting, texworks

any latex code I want to view in TexWorks 0.4.5 r.1280 (Miktex 2.9) won't show the syntax highlighting. It compiles just fine but everything line is written in black. On very long documents the highlighting shows for several seconds then the program freezes for short and the highlighting disappears again.
Windows compatibility modes did not improve the situation.
Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: When the situation is, like you tell it in your comment to Harish's answer, then it is very probably an OS related issue and therefore off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 18):

Go to `Format` → `Syntax Coloring`. In the list that appears, most probably you have `None` selected. Select `LaTeX` as in the following screen shot:

[image]

Bingo!

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, its does not work. I know how to switch it on. But that has no effects. Did you use win 8.1 for the screenshot?

Comment: It did work for me on both Windows 8.0 and 8.1. (I'm using TeX Live distribution though, which I highly recommend.)