# package for making the script in MiKTeX colorful

Tags: editors, texworks

I uninstalled my MiKTeX and now after re-installing the software, my scripts in the environment of the MiKTeX are not shown by colors.

I use **TexWorks** IDE.

for example, when you write `\usepackage{}` it is shown fully black while it used to be shown in blue color.

Entire the text is black. As another example, comments used to be shown in Green.

Which package should I install or which settings should I change in **Texworks** to do so?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: @srao Dear friend, I edited my question. I should have mentioned that I use TexWorks.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe try this..? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159062/texworks-syntax-highlighting-not-working-on-windows-8-and-8-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem of MikTeX.

You have to enable the syntax-highlighting in TeXworks.

- Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Syntax coloring
- Format -> Syntax coloring -> LaTex

Comment: Yeah, I have edited my question. The problem is solved with changing the settings in TexWorks as @srao mentioned. Anyways. Thanks dear friend.